# Error en consulta Linq ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo una consulta, la cual me genera el siguiente error

> tbl_persona is a type, whcich is not valid in the given context.

Está es la Consulta:

```
public tbl_persona ConsultaPersonaUsuario(string CodigoUsuario)
    {
        return (from persona in this.DbContext.Set<tbl_persona>()
                join usuario in this.DbContext.Set<tbl_usuariosistema>() on persona.IdPersona equals usuario.IdPersona
                join municipio in this.DbContext.Set<tbl_municipio>() on persona.IdMunicipio equals municipio.IdMunicipio
                where (usuario.CodigoUsuario == CodigoUsuario)
                select tbl_persona
                {
                    IdPersona = persona.IdPersona,
                    IdTipoDocumento = persona.IdTipoDocumento,
                    Identificacion = persona.Identificacion,
                    TipoPersona = persona.TipoPersona,
                    PrimerNombre = persona.PrimerNombre,
                    SegundoNombre = persona.SegundoNombre,
                    PrimerApellido = persona.PrimerApellido,
                    SegundoApellido = persona.SegundoApellido,
                    IdMunicipio = persona.IdMunicipio,
                    NombreMunicipio = municipio.Nombre + " " + municipio.NombreDepartamento,
                    FechaNacimiento = persona.FechaNacimiento,

                }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Alguna solución?

Comment: Prueba a guardar esa consulta en una variable y devolver dicha variable ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta :

```
           select new tbl_persona
            {
                IdPersona = persona.IdPersona,
                IdTipoDocumento = persona.IdTipoDocumento,
                Identificacion = persona.Identificacion,
                TipoPersona = persona.TipoPersona,
                PrimerNombre = persona.PrimerNombre,
                SegundoNombre = persona.SegundoNombre,
                PrimerApellido = persona.PrimerApellido,
                SegundoApellido = persona.SegundoApellido,
                IdMunicipio = persona.IdMunicipio,
                NombreMunicipio = municipio.Nombre + " " + municipio.NombreDepartamento,
                FechaNacimiento = persona.FechaNacimiento,

            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Las respuestas con sólo código pueden ser mejoradas añadiendo una explicación del problema y su solución

Comment: Tiene usted razón, gracias por el consejo.